# On Ubuntu 18.04 OpenSSL 1.1.0g - can't decrypt files, even with md5

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openssl

Previously, I was encrypting with:

```
openssl des3 -salt -in $INSECURE_CONFIG_FILE -out $CONFIG_FILE -pass pass:$PASSWORD
```

and decrypting with:

```
openssl des3 -d -salt -in $CONFIG_FILE -out $INSECURE_CONFIG_FILE -pass pass:$PASSWORD
```

I've found lots of mention of specifying -md md5 since the new default is sha256, but even with the following, I am still unable to decrypt my previously encrypted files:

```
openssl des3 -d -salt -md md5 -in $CONFIG_FILE -out $INSECURE_CONFIG_FILE -pass pass:$PASSWORD
```

I get the following error:

```
bad decrypt
140596295451072:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:../crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:536:
```

I noticed that if I add -nopad, then I get no error, but my resulted decrypted data is gibberish.

Comment: I'm not sure why someone down-voted - I'd love a comment if I'm doing something dumb here - thanks!

Comment: Had exactly the same problem, and your hint with -md md5 made it work again. Thanks! Ubuntu 18.04, OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017.

Comment: @chrisputnam9 have you found any solution?
I'm having the same trouble when encrypting with `OpenSSL 1.1.0g   2 Nov 2017` + `-md md5` and decrypting with `OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018`. I've tried decrypting with/without `-md md5` but nothing works. I've added `-pbkdf2` because the error message proposed it, but still I get `bad decrypt, envelope...`

Comment: @hudac no, I'm afraid I never did.  I gave up on it

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what I saw. I could decrypt with `-md md5`. I saw a warning regarding `pbkdf2` and thought that's an error. It did work